# be occasionally subject to abuse / be occasionlly abused

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

Is there any difference between the following sentences?

> a. Migrant workers are occasionally abused.

> b. Migrant workers are occasionally subject to abuse.

Comment: Not particularly, no

Comment: to be subject to something is not exactly the same as to be [action verb's past participle]

Answer (score 1):

In denotation, their similar. The *connotation*, being *subject to abuse*, or *subjected to abuse*, emphasizes that these are human beings who are being hurt.

For example:

- "A screwdriver used as a chisel is being abused."
- "Undocumented workers are often subject to abuse."

Comment: It's more natural to say "Migrant workers are subject to occasional abuse."

Comment: Regrettably, it's "often", not just "occasionally," for undocumented workers.